# Edit a TTF font-file then convert it to a EOT file

Tags: fonts, truetype

I have an existing .ttf font file and the corresponding .eot file which contains some graphics icons. The .eot is the file I need to reference from my css. I know this file is valid because I already use it. I need to add an extra icon. Please note that I never do that before.

[image]

**First test:** I try to open the .ttf file in an editor (Type Light 3.2) and immediately save it without changing anything. Then I converted this .ttf file to .eot file with http://ttf2eot.sebastiankippe.com/ Finally I noticed that I cannot use it from my css. No more readable?

**Another test:** directly converted my original .ttf file to .eot file with http://ttf2eot.sebastiankippe.com/ Finally I noticed that I can use it from my css.

So it seems the the conversion process is ok BUT it seems that the editor is the problem.

**My question:** is there anything special to do to be able to edit my .ttf without corrupting it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi and save a copy

Comment: you give me a link for the ttf >> eof conversion process but as I explained in my post this is not the problem. The problem is the ttf editor which seems to corrupt my ttf file.

Comment: maybe change your editor...

Comment: yes, I already try FontForge (download and install today) but it seems to crash very frequently (under Windows 7).

Comment: try fontStruct.. it's an online tool, as is BitfontMaker. With both Once you're happy with your work, you can save and download it as a TrueType font file (.ttf), install it in your computer and use it in any Windows and/or Mac application (e.g. Microsoft Office products, Photoshop and so on). You can use it as a custom web font for your site.